# Regex save all characters except between < and >

Tags: regex

In regex, I need to keep all the lines excepted all characters between `<` and `>`

For example :

```
string1<string2>string3<string4>string5
```

Result:

```
string1string3string5
```

I've just tried this but it doesn't work :

```
(?!(<[^>]*>))
```

Does someone have an idea?

Thanks,

Comment: use this `<[^<>]*>` regex and remove all the matched strings.

Answer (score 0):

You can search for this regex:

```
<[^>]*>
```

And replace it by **empty string**.

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/cJ6tK1/1)

Comment: I want as result : string1string3string5 because I want replace it by an empty string !!! (to keep <string2><string4>)

Comment: Did you check the linked demo. Output is indeed `string1string3string5` after you replace `<[^>]*>` by empty string.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the text you're working with doesn't allow nested <> or other similar constructs, the following should work (perl-style):

```
s/<[^>]*>//g
```